# GIT clone failure local data preexistent

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm using GITHUB Version 2.5.0 Desktop on my Windows machine. The folder where I want to clone my online repo into has already preexisting files. Some of them are in a more recent version than those on GITHUB. So it is obvious that I want to synchronize the MASTER branch of the online-repository into the "git init ." repo on my local disk. But this won't work, see picture. What's the use of GITHUB if I can't sync files. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: to loose less time as possible i suggest using terminal for doing that operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+into+non-empty+directory